# How to insert multiple values in a specific field in a table using mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, database-normalization, multivalue

I am working on a project and I I have a scenario like this: 
I have many field in my table :

```
table_name : transaction_tbl
-id
-name
-description
-ref_number : text(datatype)
```

In my inserting here is my code:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO transaction_tbl (`name`,`description`,`ref_number`) VALUES ('$name','$desccription',$ref_number)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === false){
                    trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . 'Error: ' . $conn->error , E_USER_ERROR);
                }else {
                    echo "Successful ! Data is inserted in database ^__^" ;

                }
```

As the name itself ref_number or reference number, so there will be a time that I will have a lot of reference number,how can I let it insert if it will have multiple values? 
Thanks :)

UPDATE :

I want something like this :

```
name    description            ref_number
bag     to be use               10359435846 
                               05438547656
                               035848576
```

Comment: Use a separate table with one row per transaction and reference number.  That is called a junction table.

Comment: how can I do that? can you give example?

Comment: You cant have multiple vals in one cell. it violates basic db rules. Just split this to two tables and have foreign keys to link thm up.
Learn db normalization. There are lot of examples. In here you need to take your un-normalized (0 nf) table to at least to 1st normalized level (1 nf). 
But its advised to make it normalized at least up to 3rd level.  https://www.google.com/search?q=db+normalizaton+guide&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=db+normalization+guide

Comment: yeah, is there no other way except making two tables that is normalize? how about if I'll just use explode?

Comment: it'll make lot of troubles for you. lot of.... performance issues. table linking issues. and you may get stucked at some point when creating some advanced queries with this structure.

Comment: so can you give example ,what should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for what purpose ? why don't you just insert a new row with the same name and description with different ref_number ?

but if you would like that , you can concatenate your new ref_number with the existing ..

first check if it already exist
get its value then concatenate the new ref number ..
or if it doesn't exist , insert a new row ..

```
$sql = "SELECT `ref_number` FROM `transaction_tbl`
WHERE `name`='$name' AND `description`='$description'";


$query = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $new_ref = $row['ref_number'] . '|' . $ref_number;
    $upd = "UPDATE `transaction_tbl` SET `ref_number`='$new_ref'
            WHERE `name`='$name' AND `description`='$description'";
}
else
{
    $ins = "INSERT INTO transaction_tbl (`name`,`description`,`ref_number`)
            VALUES ('$name','$desccription',$ref_number)";
    mysql_query($ins);
}
```

Comment: what if I will just use explode? how can I do that?

Comment: I am using also mysqli

Comment: never do this. Use two separate tables.

Comment: this is not a good practice .. like kuma DK .. just use another row / table .. but yea .. you will just have to use explode using "|"

Comment: and do not downvote bcuz i just answered what he wanted to do .. :)

Comment: just edit the answer at least a lil bit. otherwise i cant change the vote. it dose not allow.

Comment: can you guys,,give me a good example for what should I really do? thanks :)

Comment: @kumaDK : can you give example on how to do that  using two tables? because I also encounter that error ,,, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Its not a good practice to have multiple values in one cell (and you should never unless there is a serious reason). It violates basic db rules. Just split this to two tables and assign foreign keys to link them up.

Learn db normalization. There are lot of examples. In here you need to take your un-normalized (0NF) table to at least to 1st normalized level (1NF). But its advised to make it normalized at least up to 3rd level

google for db normalization tutorials. As you request below image will give you an idea(field names are not same as in your question).

[image: 0NF to 1NF]

First insert the values to table1(Member table) and get the insert id in php use  `$iid = mysqli_insert_id()`

Next add the multiple values as seperate rows into the second table(database table) along with the primary key obtained in first step.

Keep in mind this is not a tutorial site. find more info on net.